# In a Hopf algebra, is $u\epsilon (h) \otimes h = h$?

Tags: hopf-algebras

Let $(H, m, u, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ be a Hopf algebra and $h\in H$. Do we have the equality

$$u\epsilon(h)\otimes h = h$$

Or maybe put $1\otimes h$ on the RHS or something else "isomorphic"?

**EDIT**: To give the context: this is what the exercise asks me to prove:

$$\sum_{(h)} h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)})\otimes h_{(3)} = h$$

**My solution is:**
$$\sum_{(h)} h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)})\otimes h_{(3)}
\\= ((m \circ(I\otimes S))\otimes I)(\Delta \otimes I) (h)
\\= (m\circ (I\otimes S)\circ \Delta) \otimes I (h)
\\= u\epsilon (h) \otimes h
$$

Now the step I would need to make is the one in the title. Or have I already made a mistake in my calculations?

**EDIT2**: I see I made the mistake:  $\Delta_2$ should be $(I\otimes\Delta)\Delta$ so what we are actually left with is

$$(u\epsilon \otimes I) \Delta(h)$$

But how does this simplify to $h$ (or $h\otimes 1 \otimes 1$ or something like that)?

**EDIT3** Ok, now I see it:

$$(u\epsilon \otimes I) \Delta(h) = \sum_{(h)} \epsilon(h_{(1)})h_{(2)} = h$$
by the counital property as mentioned. (Or maybe you put the tensor product in there or not; there's the natural isomorphism $\mathbb{K}\otimes H \simeq H$, but I guess that goes away when you multiply: $1\otimes h = 1h = h$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: We have $\sum_{(h)} \varepsilon(h_{(1)}) h_{(2)} = h = \sum_{(h)} h_{(1)} \varepsilon(h_{(2)}) = h$ by the antipode condition … You may want to be more specific in what you’re looking for.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner I edited. Does it make any sense now?

Comment: @ploosu2 think for a moment on the outcome of $(\epsilon\otimes I)\circ\Delta$ and you'll find your answer

Comment: @JendrikStelzner actually that's the counital condition :) , The antipode Condition is $\sum_{(h)}h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)}) = u\epsilon(h) =\sum_{(h)}S(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}  $

Comment: The element $\sum_{(h)} h_{(1)} S(h_{(2)}) \otimes h_{(3)}$ lives in $H \otimes H$ and thus cannot be $h$. I think you want $\sum_{(h)} h_{(1)} S(h_{(2)}) h_{(3)} = h$ instead, which should be true. @EnderWiggins: You’re right, silly me. (I noticed it too late and couldn’t change it anymore.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to put some order, just of the sake of clarity. The antipode condition says that $$\label{antipode}\tag{$\dagger$}
\sum_{(h)}h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)}) = \varepsilon(h)1_H = \sum_{(h)}S(h_{(1)})h_{(2)}
$$
for every $h\in H$, that is to say,
$$\label{ant2}\tag{$\ddagger$}
I*S=m\circ(I\otimes S)\circ \Delta = u \circ \varepsilon = m\circ (S\otimes I)\circ \Delta=S*I.
$$
You want to prove that
$$\sum_{(h)}h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)})\otimes h_{(3)} = 1_H\otimes h$$
(which seems to me the only reasonable thing to prove, by reading your post, and it is one of the exercises on Sweedler's book, whence it seems to me a reasonable exercise that could be given to a student).

**Solution 1 (elementwise)**
\begin{align}
\sum_{(h)}h_{(1)}S(h_{(2)})\otimes h_{(3)} & = \sum_{(h)}h_{(1)_{(1)}}S(h_{(1)_{(2)}})\otimes h_{(2)} \stackrel{\eqref{antipode}}{=} \sum_{(h)}\varepsilon(h_{(1)})1_H\otimes h_{(2)} = 1_H\otimes h.
\end{align}
**Solution 2 (commutative diagrams)**
\begin{align}
(m\otimes I)\circ(I\otimes S\otimes I)\circ (\Delta\otimes I)\circ \Delta \stackrel{\eqref{ant2}}{=} (u\otimes I)\circ (\varepsilon\otimes I)\circ\Delta = u\otimes I.
\end{align}